# Can multiple people SSH into an Amazon Server instance simultaneously?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

The startup I'm working for is going to be hosting our site and accompanying database on Amazon Cloud Servers. I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple people SSH'd into the instance simultaneously, like if I want to fool around with the databases while my coworker edits some php sripts. Can this be done?

Comment: Ok sweet. That'll really speed things up in dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible :)
Just an advice use ssh-key it's better for detect/log who are logged.